# Restructuring Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe of 6 columns which has 2 major categories var1 and var 2 . i am trying to get dataframe where columns are like:
`var1(t-3)   var1(t-2)   var1(t-1)   var2(t-3)   var2(t-2)    var2(t-1)`

```
var1(t-3)   var2(t-3)   var1(t-2)   var2(t-2)   var1(t-1)   var2(t-1)
-0.37          0.13        -0.46        0.38    -0.28       -1.40
-0.46          0.38        -0.28       -1.40    -0.31        0.04
-0.28         -1.40        -0.31        0.04    -0.26       -0.71
-0.31          0.04        -0.26       -0.71    -0.19       -0.85
-0.26         -0.71        -0.19       -0.85    -0.23       -2.34
-0.19         -0.85        -0.23       -2.34    -0.23       -2.41
-0.23         -2.34        -0.23       -2.41    -0.22       -0.75
```

Comment: Could you please post a more [reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? The question is not so clear, could you put an example of what you have and what you want ?

Comment: Do you want to modify the order of the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new order of columns by `sorted` by custom lambda function:

```
c = sorted(df.columns, key = lambda x: x.split('(')[0])
```

Or more general convert numbers before `(` to `int`s:

```
c = sorted(df.columns, key = lambda x: int(x.split('(')[0].replace('var', '')))

df = df[c]
print (df)
   var1(t-3)  var1(t-2)  var1(t-1)  var2(t-3)  var2(t-2)  var2(t-1)
0      -0.37      -0.46      -0.28       0.13       0.38      -1.40
1      -0.46      -0.28      -0.31       0.38      -1.40       0.04
2      -0.28      -0.31      -0.26      -1.40       0.04      -0.71
3      -0.31      -0.26      -0.19       0.04      -0.71      -0.85
4      -0.26      -0.19      -0.23      -0.71      -0.85      -2.34
5      -0.19      -0.23      -0.23      -0.85      -2.34      -2.41
6      -0.23      -0.23      -0.22      -2.34      -2.41      -0.75
```